# I'm using JQuery to send an HTTP request to a server. It doesn't send for some reason and hits the Catch block

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

There's an issue with my code, I don't know what it is. I censored out a part that would reveal my name.

I know that it's not an issue with the server, as I checked it's not sending any requests.

If the fix is super simple, please don't mock me for being a JQuery/JS noob. Thanks!

```
function getBalance() {
  var balance;
  try {
    $.get(
        "https://[censored]-backend-system.glitch.me/balance/",
        {login: username},
        function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          data = balance;
        }
    );
  } catch {
    console.log("catch")
    return 0;
  }

  return balance;
}
```

EDIT: TypeError: $.get is not a function? I have JQuery on my HTML, don't I..? I'll go test that.

EDIT 2: I have JQuery installed on my HTML, my JS is after where JQuery is installed... what

Comment: check the browser developer tools for details ... also, change the catch to `catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return 0;` so you can see what the error actually is in the first place - Interesting that you chose to use `catch` rather than `catch(e)` ... the former is a very new allowed format - so, you're up to date with current javascript - just not debugging your own code

Comment: why don't you just remove the `try catch` block for to see the error. or log the caught error.

Comment: thanks guys I'm going to do that right now!

Comment: `I have JQuery on my HTML, don't I.` - did you load it in a script tag? we don't know

Comment: I loaded it, yes.

Comment: Do check the jQuery file is loaded or not. May some time file path could be the issue.

Comment: `I have JQuery installed on my HTML` exactly how? do you have async or defer attribute on the script tag?

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

Comment: The copy of jQuery obtained from that source appears to not define `$.get`.  Indeed, it appears to not have any HTTP request functionality.  I think you shouldn't be using the "slim" version of jQuery.